# Different output at different times when getchar() is used

Tags: c

In this program (which basically copies the input into an array & finally display it) -->

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c,i=0;
    char arr[100];

    while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
    {
        if((((c>=65)&&(c<=90))||((c>=97)&&(c<=122)))||(c==' ')||(c=='\t'))
        arr[i]=c;
        i++;
    }

    printf("\n%s in print\n",arr);

  return 0;
}
```

As to pass **EOF** successfully, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> was needed to be pressed twice or generally after hitting ENTER. So I wrote this version to allow only certain characters into the array. But the output is very dubious, sometimes it is giving error free output, other times it is not. Here is the output of two runs:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`printf` `%s` takes a string. You're passing it `arr`, which is not a string. A string needs a `'\0'` terminator to mark the end.

Answer (score 0):

`arr` is char array and it should be *null terminated*. when statement

`printf("\n%s in print\n",arr);` executes `%s` format try to print until `'\0'` character, but in your case there is no `'\0'` at the end so it prints some junk data.

```
while((c=getchar())!=EOF) {
              if((((c>=65)&&(c<=90))||((c>=97)&&(c<=122)))||(c==' ')||(c=='\t'))
              arr[i]=c;
              i++;
 }
```

when loop fails put the `'\0'` char at last.

`arr[i] = '\0'`

Comment: `NULL` is a pointer, not a character. It's unrelated to strings.

Comment: yes @melpomene `NULL` is void pointer `(void*)0` .I was wrong above.